# Explain how lottery is haram in definition

Tags: fiqh, definitions

First of all please refrain from saying things like these:

**'because Allah made it forbidden for you'**...that's **what i am asking**, where does it say that lottery is haram. Or why do you interpret it that way.

**'it causes bad luck to winner'**....how is that a reason… the bad luck is a result of bad choices that person makes once he/she has lots of money once he has won. It's like using knife is haram because it is used by murderers to kill.

**'it causes people to loss everything and get addicted.'**....again isn't this the person doing the act in wrong and not the act itself. If you have limited money, would you rather spend it on what you need and not what you want.

**'Follow Islam, it's beneficial for you'**.. unless you didn't notice that is my intention that's why i am asking this question, which btw asks why and not if it's beneficial to ...

Second thing is that people say it's a form of gambling, i do agree that gambling is haram that is clear to me from Islam. However, is this gambling. To me gambling has always been people sit together to play some games where outcome and profit is based on randomness. But i am sure there is a description of gambling...so i guess main question is **please define gambling as in Islam and how lottery fits in it.**

The reasons that i have read so far these, but they are conflicting or lack something...

**'there is no skill involved it's up to pure chance'** ..so is it ok if there is some skill and some chance, than why is poker haram there sure is chance, what cards do you get, but also skill too is needed. And whose skill, skill of person, animal, computer, investor, worker.

**'there is no added value'**.. basically argument goes that difference between gambling and business/trade is that in trade you exchange things that have value so even if you make a loss in your trade because of bad luck/information/dynamic market... product still holds some value. ...which is not true always bought product can become worthless or even liability. which one is it, skill or value that matters? So if lottery is gambling then how is it different from investment.... What is a difference between gambling and investment? You invest it could be profitable or loss...so is lottery. though chances are low

I do agree gambling is bad for us…) it promotes activity that doesn't create wealth but gives hopes to participants by circulating existing wealth at cost of time so as a group it's a total loss. b) as it's the case most of the times, for a group of 10, there is a total and definite loss for 9 members over which they have not control. In business they could at least try.

Answer (score 4):

Gambling is Haram in Islam based on Quran and many hadith.

> Satan only wants to cause between you animosity and hatred through
>   intoxicants and gambling and to avert you from the remembrance of
>   Allah and from prayer. So will you not desist? http://tanzil.net/#5:91

Scholars have said different definitions for gambling:

1. Making a bond and setting some terms and playing by some playing
   tools that are made for gambling.
2. Playing by tools that are for gambling even if there is no bound and
   income.
3. Playing for winning, regardless of using tools made for gambling or
   any other tools.

**Reference:**

[What is reason of gambling without bound being Haram?](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa21629)

---

About what you said for investment there are some forms of permitted contracts and business in Islam. If investment fits in any of them it is Halal and if not it is not Halal. If investment is a form of gambling and it is practices in Islamic countries it is not an acceptable proof than lottery will be Halal. For lottery to be Halal Islamic reason is needed (verse of Quran and authentic hadith). The practices of Muslims can be un-Islamic. Only practices of an [infallibles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fourteen_Infallibles) are 100% Islamic.